# Table UI design

Tags: html, css, row

There are 4 rows in a table to user to fill.

The first row MUST NOT be empty.

The others are optional.

How to create the look and feel to announce that?

Should be in pure html and css plus jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Look at various forms out there on the interwebs and pick what you like best. Star`*` every required field, **bolden** or *italicize* it, write "The following fields are required/optional", paint them red, use exclamation mark icons. It's completely up to you and what fits your current design.
There's no rocket surgery behind this. :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest having the first row visible, and with a required sign (red *) next to it. Then, when the user starts filling it out, show the next row. When the user fills that, show the third.